# New APNS certificates

Tags: apple-push-notifications

I have a question I sort of run into misunderstanding. I have created new Apns certificate `p8` and I have more applications with different budnle ids. Do I need to create apns certificate for all of them or just one? Does it only depend on the `teamid` ? Or what's is the deal

Comment: here is what I have found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67308054/sendemptypushnotification-to-gateway-push-apple-com-no-longer-working/67309911?noredirect=1#comment118996327_67309911